# Is there any way to delete all Runs with stages= canceled or failed in the Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am new to Azure DevOps. I have created one pipeline. WHich has multiple runs with stage=  canceled or failed. I want to delete it. Is there any way to delete all Runs with stages= canceled or failed in the Azure pipeline?

I can see the option to delete a specific run but am unable to see any option to delete multiple runs at a time.

Answer (score 1):

From UI, there is no option to delete all target runs once. Only able to delete the whole build pipeline.

As an alternative, you can enable filter on the pipeline, filter out the target pipelines, and delete them one by one. Screenshot as below, you can filter on release pipeline as well.
[image]

How many stages on your pipeline? If the target runs failed or has same property, you can use [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to list the target runs(with filter in the rest api)， get the build run id, and then [delete them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) via script.
[image]